# Smallest animal that produces food for humans

Tags: zoology

I was thinking about how bees can produce honey and human can eat it. After that I came up with question. What are the smallest animal that can produce food for human?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on what you consider food, but if you consider things that contribute to food substances (e.g. food dyes) then [cochineal scale mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochineal) are only about 5 mm (0.2 in) long and produce a red dye that is commonly used as a food colorant.

There are also several ant species of similar size that are eaten as food sources. For example, *[Liometopum apiculatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liometopum_apiculatum)* (6-7 mm adult) grubs are/were harvested as a food source in parts of the USA and Mexico.

Comment: I cannot find the size of Chaoborus edulis but they might be a contender: [Kunga cake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunga_cake).

Comment: @Roland I knew of that one, but didn't know the name or which region of Africa it was from, so I didn't try to find it. You should write your own answer based on this. [Bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/41232) suggests 8-10 mm for the genus.

Comment: I'll throw in my 2 cents and say fungi, especially yeast (or other fungi used for blue-cheese etc.), typically measuring 3–4 µm in diameter and could be perceived as 'producer' since it's converting sugars via fermentation..

Comment: @iLuvLogix That's not an animal as OP requested.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks for pointing that out - a quick search revealed that they seem to have a seperate kingdom of their own (besides plants and animals) - my bad..